# How to remove the last character of a directory name from multiple files

Tags: directory, rename

I am trying to remove one character from multiple directory names but I am unsure on how to set up a loop for this.

```
Part to remove is '1' (the last digit in the directory name)
e.g. S123451/
     S234561/
     S345671/
```

Also, I am trying to remove portion of a file name from multiple files in subfolders but I am unsure on how to set up a loop for this.

```
Part to remove '_*_*_*****' (everything after the 1st underscore up to before the file extension)

e.g  S123451/
        /9/
          S12345_1_9_00001.nii.gz
        /4/
          S12345_1_4_00001.nii.gz
          S12345_1_4_00001.bval
          S12345_1_4_00001.bvec
 S234561/
        /2/
          S23456_1_2_00001.nii.gz
        /1/
          S23456_1_1_00001.nii.gz
          S23456_1_1_00001.bval
          S23456_1_1_00001.bvec
 S345671/
        /5/
          S34567_1_5_00001.nii.gz
        /20/
          S34567_1_20_00001.nii.gz
          S34567_1_20_00001.bval
          S34567_1_20_00001.bvec
```

Answer (score 0):

With Larry Wall's `rename` (Debian/ubuntu) or `prename` (Fedora/RHEL/CentOS):

#### Directories:

```
rename -n 's/.$//' *
```

in other words, replace the last character by nothing. `-n` is for dry runs, remove or replace by `-v` for actual execution. If you use the `*/` pattern to make sure you list only directories:

```
rename -n 's:./$::' */
```

#### Files:

```
rename -n 's/_[^.]+//' *
```

in other words, replace the first underscore and everything that follows that is not a dot by nothing.